# Jenkins Jira Plugin: Cannot create new issue

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jira-plugin

I want to create a jira issue with the Jenkins Jira Steps plugin in my jenkins pipeline with groovy and I have the following code in a stage:

```
def buildIssue = [fields: [project: [key: 'OLSSCHED'],
                           summary: 'test',
                           issuetype: [id: '10102']]]                               
def response = jiraNewIssue issue: buildIssue
echo response.successful.toString()
echo response.data.toString()
```

The issuetype only requires the field 'summary' and also only shows the field 'summary' when creating it interactively in Jira.

But I get an error message when trying to create it via Jenkins pipeline stating the following:

> Error Message: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"description":"Field
>   'description' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or
>   unknown."}}

I am not trying to the set description field. Does anyone know if the plugin internally tries to set this field? Or why does it throw such an error?

Comment: Error message implies the documentation is inconsistent and the `description` argument is required.

Comment: If you configured your JIRA to have a mandatory 'description' field, your code needs to provide the contents of the field, otherwise JIRA will (rightly) refuse to create the issue.

Comment: But the 'description' field is not marked as mandatory in JIRA... It gives the same error, if I try to set the description field.